# php unable to read characters in utf8

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do the simple following:

```
<?php
 header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dsdsds","test1234","dsdsds");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM discounts");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['rate'];
  echo "<br>";
  }




?>
```

When I do this, my output shows as ??????. in the database table, it is showing as Arabic correctly. What am I doing wrong? also I know I should add code to set mysqli to utf8 and when I do, it breaks script.

```
  if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
        printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    } else {
        printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
    }
```

Looking forward to your support

Comment: It may sound stupid but did you check that your files are encoded in UTF-8? Also you can try to run this query right after connecting: `SET NAMES utf8;`

Comment: what error does it print?

Comment: is your database tables utf-8 encoded and the data look ok?

Answer (score 4):

mysqli has two ways to call methods. Procedural and Object-oriented. You'll see in the documentation both methods.

This is the procedural style:

```
$con=mysqli_connect...
$result = mysqli_query...
$row = mysqli_fetch_array...
```

This is the OO style:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost"...
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
$result = $mysqli->query...
$row = $mysqli->fetch_array...
```

It looks like you are mixing the styles. Change `$mysqli->set_charset` to `$mysqli_set_charset` and try again.

If you would like my opinion, I prefer the OO style.

Comment: The OO style is better because it's basically impossible to pass the handle to the wrong method by accident.